# "who/which surround us" or "around us"

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-choice

Are these phrases interchangeable, or is there any difference? Which one is more idiomatic?

> We reach out to ***the people who surround us*** or ***the people around us***?

> We have cut ***the trees which/that surround us*** or ***the trees around us***?

Comment: I'm not happy with this answer but I'll still leave it as a comment for others to discuss:

Comment: In my opinion, there is quite a big difference. Unless you are being rather poetic, *surround* refers to obvious physical presence in the here and now. Furthermore, the phrases sound better as *the *x* surrounding us*.

The *around* versions, on the other hand, can be understood much more generally, especially the *people* phrase, as simply meaning 'the people who live in the same community as us'.